# How do I take the symbol from user for formatting a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, numbers, runtime-error

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
echo 
echo " Enter the number of rows you want : "
read rows


echo

for row in $(seq 1 $rows)
do
    for col in $(seq 1 $row)
    do
         sum=$(( $sum + 1 ))
         
         echo -n "$sum "
    done
    echo
done
```

It prints the output I want,

```
1
23
456
```

But I don't want to start my code from 1, I want user to enter the number. So I tried to modify, but it still does not give the desired output.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
echo 
echo " Enter the number of rows you want : "
read rows

echo " Enter the number you want to start with : "
read num
echo

for row in $(seq $num $rows)
do
     for col in $(seq $num $row)
     do
          sum=$(( $sum + 1 ))
          
          echo -n "$sum "
     done
     echo
done
```

Even if I enter the num.
This gives me no output at all. It just does not show anything.
Can anyone tell where am I going wrong? I cant figure it out.

Comment: How did you try modifying it, and what error did you get?

Comment: Yes, now I edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: What number did you input for `rows` and `num`? It looks working.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Is `num` supposed to be the starting row/column number (which your code seems to use it as), or the starting value for the numbers being printed (which I assumed from your description)? If you want the second, you need to input the starting value for `sum` instead of a separate starting number for the `seq` commands.

Comment: AND if you add `set -x` near the top of your script, you'll see each line execute with the values set for each variable. `set -vx` give you a verbose view, but also outputs the complete body of any loops, before showing the line-by-line output. You can turn these off with `set +x` (or `set +vx`. ). Good luck.